# Ubuntu 22.10 Modeset Error

Tags: nvidia, gnome, firefox, 22.10

I am running Ubuntu 22.10 (i7 9700KF + RTX 2080) with Nvidia driver version 525.xx, on X11. Recently I have been noticing micro-freezes (around 1-2 seconds) on unlocking, and sometimes while tab-switching in Firefox. These are the only occurrences, and other GPU intensive tasks (like gaming etc.) does not cause any freezes or slowdown. The only thing I could find of any relevance in the logs that correlate with the freezes is this error:

```
[drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? There seems to be launchpad bug report, but without much info in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

I get micro-freezes+ running 525.xx on X11 and GNOME `42.9` on 22.04. I just recovered from a macro-freeze that required a hard power cycle. I was running Blender when the last system hangup started. dmesg last entries show plenty of your ~same message

> nvidia_drm ... ERROR ... "Failed to grab modeset ownership"

Answers I've seen so far advise updating grub to include this directive:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nvidia-drm.modeset=1"`

The reasoning / detail are in the threads below. I'm going to reboot, fire up Blender and will report back here.

Three active threads I researched:

- https://forums.opensuse.org/t/solution-to-nvidia-drm-failed-to-grab-modeset-ownership/148509
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-21-10-failed-to-grab-modeset-ownership-with-495-44/193867/7
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/706349